# how do i get the dream suite in acnl 2019

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

i have been playing since 2015 and i'm still playing today, it is currently 2019 and i now just realized that there is more to do in this game,i have literally tried going back in time (in the game)and looked in the town hall to see if Isabelle was sleeping but she wasn't ,can someone help me get the dream suite when its 2019?!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to build at least one public works project, be mayor for 7 days and have connected to the Internet once.